# Crontab + Subprocess saving files

Tags: python, subprocess, cron

I've written small testing program in Python and now I have big problem to run it with Crontab (from command line works perfect)

The problem probably is connected with subprocess. Here you can check my function:

```
def sipp_start(sip_account,sip_account_pass,sip_server):
    sipp_cmd = ['/usr/bin/sipp', sip_account, sip_account_pass, sip_server]
    sipp = subprocess.Popen(sipp_cmd,stdout=devnull,stderr=devnull)
    status =  sipp.wait()
    pid = sipp.pid

    return (pid,status);
```

sip_cmd as a result create few statistics files. When I set this script in crontab I don't get this files, and get error:

> Can't open the stat file.

Any ideas how to deal with it?

Comment: Most of the problems with crontab are because the environment might not be what you expect, in particular start-up files like .bashrc are not run, depending on the shell.  Make sure that all filenames are fully qualified and none are relative.

Comment: That's true, but subprocess save files in directory where we run it. Unfortunately I can't set full path for this files.

Comment: So far as I am aware, subprocess does not save any files.   /usr/bin/sipp might though.  By the way, you can change the current directory with a parameter to Popen.

Comment: Changed to: sipp = subprocess.Popen(sipp_cmd,stdout=devnull,stderr=devnull,cwd='/opt/sip_tester/'), but result is the same.

Comment: I would try to change the stderr params in popen function to see if the sipp command have some error messege.

Comment: I honestly cannot see how this is Python related.  That's a rubbish error message, it should tell you the error number (e.g. ENOENT or EPERM) and the full filename.  So where is it coming from if not from sipp?  Open a file for write then set stderr to the file object.

Comment: The error string: Can't open the stat file. is set by my function exception, which try to open files created by sipp. Stderr does't present anything interesting (Error opening terminal: unknown. - the same as running from command line).

Comment: Any other idea ? Maybe some changes in crontab enviroment can solve it ?

Comment: try to run `sipp` via crontab using  fixed parameters, log stdout, stderr. If it works then use the same *fixed* parameters to run using `subprocess` in Python. If it works start replacing the fixed  (hardcoded) parameters with variables until it breaks.